# Java heap space when adding documents to List of documents

Tags: java, xml, out-of-memory

I am using import org.w3c.dom.Document; for document.

I have this block of code that parses the xml file from the arraylist fileList, there are more than 2000 xml files to be parsed and size of the xml files are around 30-50 Kb, I have no problem parsing the files:

```
    try {
        for(int i = 0; i < fileList.size(); i++) {
            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = builder.parse(fileList.get(i)); //<------ error will point here when docList.add(doc) is uncommented.
            docList.add(doc); 
        }
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException | SAXException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**but whenever I add them to the list this error comes up:**

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl.createChunk(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl.ensureCapacity(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl.createNode(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl.createDeferredTextNode(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractDOMParser.characters(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.test.parser.Parser.getDocs(Parser.java:146)
    at com.test.parser.Parser.main(Parser.java:50)

**uncommenting the docList.add(doc) does not produce this exception, any idea why this is happening?**

**EDIT: I added -Xmx1024M to VMArguments in Run Configurations and it worked.**

Comment: Why do you create new instances of everything each time you go through the loop?

Comment: Pretty rough estimation says that you will need about 140 MB of RAM. Increase the Java Heap Size with: `-Xmx400M`.

Comment: @csmckelvey, I am just experimenting with the code since I got this error, I have a different DocumentBuilder outside the for loop.

Comment: I wouldn't make any solution based on increasing heap size, unless I REALLY have to. fileList.size() always might be larger, so this makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

`uncommenting the docList.add(doc) does not produce this exception, any idea why this is happening?`

It's simple: without storing `doc` reference in `docList`, doc reference will be overrived by new object - `Document doc = builder.parse(fileList.get(i));`, so the `doc` from previous iteration will be orphan - object without reference. This one will be fastly removed by JVM garbage collector, so during loop you will have at most 2 doc objects on the heap.

But, with `docList.add(doc)` active, you will still have references to all doc objects created in loop:  exactly `fileList.size()` instances. They aren't collected (and removed from heap) by garbage collector, because `docList` will have valid, active references to them.

How to avoid `OutOfMemoryError`? Just parse / process document one by one, after destroying DOM object of previous doc, or consider using streaming parser, for example `SAXParser`.

Answer (score 0):

right click on project folder
click -> runAs -> run Configuration -> click on arguments tab -> add

-xmx512M   press Enter
-xmx2048M

Apply and Run.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This original question made no reference to any particular IDE, so this advice can't be put to action without more information. Likewise, this does not answer the OP's question, which relates to the cause of the exception, not how to possibly mitigate it. This post would likely be better left as a comment below the main post, or deleted altogether.